# AWS Athena with Power BI Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, powerbi

We have recently able to connect Power BI desktop with AWS athena through ODBC,
Now we would like to publish report to Power BI services.

My query is , how to setup a gateway for AWS Athena? as I understood gateway is only applicable for on premise databases, therefore is it applicable for AWS Athena?

Thanks and Regards
Rajib

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the [PowerBI Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) application and install it on the machine that is supposed to act as a gateway.

Once you have this done you need to also setup the Athena ODBC connection on this machine too, probably with a similar name. Afterwards you can configure the report to use this gateway to refresh the dataset.

Comment: Is there a logical explanation on why on-premises gateway is required to access the data in Athena which is available from anywhere on the Internet? I'm finding this advice again and again but don't understand why it should be this way...

Comment: @demosito [Amazon's own blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/creating-dashboards-quickly-on-microsoft-power-bi-using-amazon-athena/) (Shitij Mathur's answer) showcases using Athena with the Power BI Service using a Power BI Gateway with the Simba Athena ODBC Driver. I'm don't think there's another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start by designing a dashboard in Microsoft Power BI Desktop with the help of the Athena data source connector for Power BI and the Athena ODBC driver.
2. When you finish creating your dashboard, you publish it to the Microsoft Power BI Service. To see your data on Microsoft Power BI Service, you need to install the Microsoft Power BI on-premises data gateway in your AWS account—it works like a bridge between Microsoft Power BI Service and Athena.
3. Finally, you configure Athena as a new data source in Microsoft Power BI Service.

Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/creating-dashboards-quickly-on-microsoft-power-bi-using-amazon-athena/